# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Cannot access a closed file.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on web API core and returning `IActionResult`. One of my API throws error while returning `FileResult`.

I get the following error.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Cannot access a closed file.'.

My code is something like :

```
FileStream zipToOpen;

using (zipToOpen = new FileStream(Path.Combine(reportsPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) + ".zip", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            int index = document.Path.LastIndexOf("/");
            if (index != -1)
                fileName = document.Path.Substring(index + 1);
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(document.Path, fileName);                            
        }
    }

    //zipToOpen.Position = 0;
    return File(zipToOpen, "application/zip", "MyDocuments.zip");
}
```

Can anyone please help me what's the issue.

Comment: Check the sources for `ZipArchive`, perhaps it disposes the `FileStream` when you dispose it.

Comment: Move the return 1 level up to right behind the foreach loop

Comment: @zaitsman we can specify options to open/close stream. but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @Rafaeltab no luck.

Comment: I just wanted to create zip archive and send it back to response with file result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in another answer the file stream is being disposed of before the framework has had time to completed its functionality. That is because you are returning the stream in a `using` block which will dispose of the stream once the out of scope.

If there is no need for the archive to actually be saved/written to disk, consider building the archive in memory and return its stream.

```
//...

MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var zipArchive  = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true)) {
    foreach (var document in documents) {
        string fileName = document.Path;
        int index = fileName.LastIndexOf("/");
        if (index != -1)
            fileName = fileName.Substring(index + 1);
        zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(document.Path, fileName);
    } 
} // disposal of archive will force data to be written to memory stream.
zipStream.Position = 0; //reset memory stream position.
return File(zipStream, "application/zip", "MyDocuments.zip");
```

Note the memory stream will be disposed by the `FileResult` once it is finished with it.

Comment: thank you. it's really helpful to me. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with a stream, so until the stream is flushed or closed, you still need the component pieces like your `ZipArchive`. The problem is that you're returning the stream outside of the `using` statement where `zipArchive` sill exists. If you move your return inside that `using` block, you should be fine.